# position within html for angular <script> tag

Tags: html, angularjs

I have been handed a project that will combine CodeIgniter with AngularJS.  Since i have no real world exp. with angular, I have been going through the tuts.  I have noticed sporadic issues with where the html script tag that locates the angular.js file.  Some of the tutorials have the script tag within the html  tag and some of the tuts have the script tag down at the bottom (before the closing  tag).  When inserted within the head tag, it works every time.  But when placed down at the bottom, my tut app has issues.  Like it wont recognize the {{variable}} and do what its supposed to.  Should angular work at both locations??  I was always taught that the only javascript reference that goes in the head is Respond.js and the modernizr.js.  Everything else can be located at the bottom of the html page  I am using the most recent stable version of angular.

Tony

Comment: Thanks rjm226!  I looked in the prior questions for the answer and I think I just missed seeing it in the return of answered questions.  Sorry peeps for re-asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the best place to put <script> tags in HTML markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place it just before the closing body tag. This way the JavaScript is executed after loading the html.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose the way you want, since it's a SPA => loaded once so no poor performance if in head.

If you declare `angular.js`on the bottom part of the page, there's a good way to avoid the case 
for missed interpolated variable:
You should use the [`ng-bind`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBind) directive in your home template instead of the direct interpolation notation:

```
<div ng-bind="model.value"></div>
```

instead of `{{model.value}}`